# Is it optional to specify Type in HTML 5 video source?

Tags: html, html5-video

Is it optional to specify Type in HTML 5 video source? Or we have to specify it? can any one plz help me in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is optional. The browser will just have to download the header of each source file to check if it can play it. Specifying type allows the browser to skip the ones it definitely can't play.